# Passing array off as reference in c++ without using pointer

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a quick question regarding an assignment I have to complete for C++. The teacher has required that I include the functions below:

```
void getPlayerInfo(Player &);
void showInfo(Player);
int getTotalPoints(Player [], int);
```

But I'm having trouble working on the first function....I'm not sure if I'm calling the array of structures properly. Can someone look it over and see what I'm doing wrong? I fiddled with it a bit and I'm able to call the array and pass off a pointer to the array but the teacher requested the "&" symbol be there so there must be another method I'm unaware of. Please help! Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Structure to hold information about a player
struct Player
{
    string name;        // to hold the players name
    int number;         // to hold players number
    int points;         // to hold the points scored by the player
};

// Function prototypes
void getPlayerInfo(Player &); // function to get the players information       from the user
void showInfo(Player);    // function to show the table

int main()
{
    const int numPlayers = 12;  // Constant to hold the number of players
    Player team[numPlayers];    // array to hold 12 structures

                            // Gather information about all 12 players
    getPlayerInfo(team);

    showInfo(team);


    return 0;
}

// Function to get the players info
void getPlayerInfo(Player& team)
{
   for (int count = 0; count < 12; count++)
{
    cout << "PLAYER #" << (count + 1) << endl;
    cout << "----------" << endl;
    cout << "Player name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, team[count].name);
    cout << "Player's number: ";
    cin >> team[count].number;
    cout << "Points scored: ";
    cin >> team[count].points;
    cout << endl;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you even listen to the leacture your professor should've given you? Looks like you did not, so now you need to read a book on C++.

Comment: @SergeyA Perhaps you overestimate them professors. Or maybe it's just me with all the bad experience...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getPlayerInfo()` does not accept an array, it accepts a reference to a single `Player` object.

You need to call `getPlayerInfo()` for each player in your array. Move your loop outside of `getPlayerInfo()` and into `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood the intent of these functions.

Guessing from the information you've provided, `getPlayerInfo` is intended to get the information of an *individual* player, and `showPlayerInfo` is intended to show the information of an *individual* player.

You're trying to use these functions to do something they aren't intended to do, so it's a good thing that you are having trouble figuring out how to call and how to implement them.

Consider this experience as a object lesson in requirement gathering.